# VideoCapture does not play the video

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, video-capture

I have a problem with `VideoCapture` where the video I am streaming shows only the 1st frame. In the following code I superimpose a video on top of the bounding box yielded from object detection:

```
if view_img:
            ####video_name is a path to my video 
            img = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
            ret_video, frame_video = img.read()
            if not ret_video: ######so that the video can be played in a loop
                img = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
                ret_video, frame_video = img.read()
            
            ###here I look for the bounding boxes and superimpose the video 
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 120, 120), (10, 255, 255))#(110, 120, 120), (130, 255, 255))#<- blue # RED: (0, 120, 120), (10, 255, 255)) 
            thresh = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
            contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            #contours = contours[0]
            contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
            #frame_counter = 0
            for contour in contours:
                if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 750:
                    continue
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)                                        
                height = 480
                width = 640                                     
                if y + h < height and x + w < width:                                            
                        logo = cv2.resize(frame_video, (w, h))###frame_video is the frame from the video which I superimpose
                        img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(logo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                        _, logo_mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                        roi = im0[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                        roi[np.where(logo_mask)] = 0
                        roi += logo            
        cv2.imshow(str(p), im0)# im0 is the webcam frame         
        cv2.waitKey(25)
```

What happens when I run this code, is that instead of showing the entire video on top of the webcam frame, it displays only the first frame of that video.

Superimposing video works fine in another script, modified original: [source](https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/opencv-python-webcam-how-to-track-and-replace-object/)

I believe that the issue has something to do with `waitKey()` for the superimposed video, as it is not specified.

If I try to initialize the video with `while (cap.isopened()):` or `while (True)` then the program freezes and there is no output at all.

Comment: Edit: 
Sometimes, there are other frames from the superimposed video in the output, but that happens rarely.

Comment: What is im0? Shouldnt it be frame_video?

Comment: @Micka im0 is the frame from the webcam. frame_video is the frame from the superimposed video. I take frame_video and add it to the webcam frame im0

Comment: @Micka I believe that the contours are found successfully, since the overlay does work with a singular image or the first frame from the superimposed image/video. The problem is that the rest of the frames from the video are not being displayed.

Comment: Where is im0 generated/captured?!?

Comment: @Micka 
im0 comes from the other class, LoadWebcam: [here] (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/utils/datasets.py)

Comment: Are you running view_img in a loop, or how do you expect to process more than 1 frame?

Comment: @Micka
Yes, view_img is a part of the loop which handles the object detection. So that when I run the script the object detection happens until I terminate the program.
view_img steams the results of the object prediction to the screen.

Comment: With  
            img = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
            ret_video, frame_video = img.read() you always read the first image of the video file. So with your code, no matter how often you call view_img, you always only read the very first frame of that videofile.

Comment: @Mika
Can you please suggest how could I read the entire video? This is exactly the problem I have tried to describe in the original post.

Comment: put everything starting with ret_video, frame_video = img.read() in a loop until ret becomes false

Comment: @Micka
Thank you for your time!

toyota Supra has shown how it is implemented in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it. You simply do like this: Btwe

```
if view_img:
            ####video_name is a path to my video 
            img = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
            while img.isOpened():
                ret_video, frame_video = img.read()
                if not ret_video: ######so that the video can be played in a loop
                    break
                
                ###here I look for the bounding boxes and superimpose the video 
                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 120, 120), (10, 255, 255))#(110, 120, 120), (130, 255, 255))#<- blue # RED: (0, 120, 120), (10, 255, 255)) 
                thresh = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
                contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                #contours = contours[0]
                contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
                #frame_counter = 0
                for contour in contours:
                    if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 750:
                        continue
                    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)                                        
                    height = 480
                    width = 640                                     
                    if y + h < height and x + w < width:                                            
                            logo = cv2.resize(frame_video, (w, h))###frame_video is the frame from the video which I superimpose
                            img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(logo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                            _, logo_mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                            roi = im0[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                            roi[np.where(logo_mask)] = 0
                            roi += logo            
                cv2.imshow(str(p), im0)# im0 is the webcam frame         
                cv2.waitKey(25)
```

Btw, If you are using OpenCV4.5.5. You may have to add this:

```
ret,contours = cv2.findContours
```

Answer (score 3):

`cv2.VideoCapture` should be run once for each device source. Using `while loop` should exclude `cv2.VideoCapture` (initialize it outside the loop). The reason why it's hang on `while loop` because you open up the connection for the same device multipletimes without closing it.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense why the script crashes if there's more than one while loop present. 
Do you have any suggestion why does the superimposed video prioritizes the first frame from the video?